# Scale android big screen to iphone screen resolution & density (Phonegap Build)

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, cordova

I developed an app in phonegap build and going to publish as i see it work nicely in iphone resolution. When the time i try with samsung note, i found out the screen resolution not so good as the application look small and minimized everything. How can i scale the application and fit to the screen as how it fit to iphone screen? Thanks for reply.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

Comment: Use super.appView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true); in Activity oncreate method.

Comment: @rpelluru, can you please give me more details please. Thanks.

Comment: public class MyActivity extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 70000);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
  
  if (super.appView != null) {
         super.appView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
   super.appView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
  }
    }
    
}

Answer (score 0):

If you want resolve this without using native code, e.g. if you're using Phonegap build service, you can set target-densitydpi=160 or some other value. This will will set the dpi (dots per inch) for the device. This way the content will be sized similarly across devices. Standard values:

- Low res: target-densitydpi=120
- Medium res: target-densitydpi=160
- High res: target-densitydpi=240

As I understand it, you can use any value between 70-400.

**Word of caution:** I've just made use of this on a Phonegap app of my own, and am experiencing troubles with un-clickable areas, which I'm currently researching. My app is a little complex and heavy on the DOM, so I'm not sure if this will be a problem for you. Just make sure to test all click/tap events extensively after implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content','width=1024, user-scalable=no'); 
});
```

Seem to work for disabling the user scaling after the correct scaling have been applied

Comment: how you know what's the exact width for all the devices?